# Dowloading list of References from Google Scholar

Tags: java, web-scraping, google-scholar

I have stored the references from a research paper in a list (as shown below): I want to download them all from google scholar. I have successfully downloaded a single paper by giving its url below, What I need to do now is that as i have stored all the references from Research paper in the list(there are 15 references in list which means atleast 5 of them would be in pdf), I want to run the list on Google Scholar and download the avaialble pdfs of references. If pdf is not avaialble for a reference, it must display "Pdf is not avaialable": I have shared the code to download a single one, I dont know how to ammend the code for the list to download multiple papers.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
               Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("D:\\ref.txt"));

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (s.hasNextLine()){
    list.add(s.nextLine());
    {
        for (String Z : list)
        {
            System.out.println(Z);

        }
    }
}
//System.out.println("LISTZ:" +list);
s.close();//LIST completed



        //code to download the paper from scholar
try {
   //var a= doc.replace(" ","+");

    Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect("https://scholar.google.com.pk/scholar?q=%5B3%5D+W.+H.+Walters%2C+%E2%80%9CGoogle+scholar+coverage+of+a+multidisciplinary+field%2C%E2%80%9D+Information+Processing+%26+Management+%2C+vol.+43%2C+no.+4%2C+pp.+1121+%E2%80%93+1132%2C+July+2007.&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")
            .get();

    String title = doc.title();
    System.out.println("title : " + title);


    Elements links = doc.select("div.gs_ggsd").select("a[href]");
    //Element  = doc.select("div.gs_ggs gs_fl").first();

    for (Element link : links) {
        //System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
        URL website = new URL(link.attr("href"));
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\paper.pdf");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
} 
       // System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
    }
  /* ByteArrayOutputStream href = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(href);
PrintStream old = System.out;
System.setOut(PS);
System.out.println("Here: " + href.toString());*/


    catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}



    }




}
```

Comment: What is in ref.txt? url or fileName?

Comment: "[1] J. Bailey, C. Zhang, D. Budgen, M. Turner, and S. Charters, “Search engine overlaps : Do they agree or disagree?” in Second International Workshop on Realising Evidence-Based Software Engineering (REBSE '07) , 2007, p. 2. [Online]. Available:
           http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=42732 74"
 The above string is in ref.txt and many others like it. (authors name, paper title, year of publish, conference or journal etc) basically ref.txt contains filename, file authors, file years of publish and place of publish.

Comment: You want to do what using all theses contents? As a query condition?

Comment: YES, this will go as a query as i have shown in my code, then download the paper in the div, where the pdf file is residing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just pass the query to the Url with a loop:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * User: lihongxu
 * Date: 17/6/13
 * Time: 19:42
 * Comments
 */
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("D:\\ref.txt"));

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            list.add(s.nextLine());
            {
                for (String Z : list) {
                    System.out.println(Z);

                }
            }
        }
        s.close();// LIST completed


        // code to download the paper from scholar
        for (String query : list) {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup
                        .connect("https://scholar.google.com.pk/scholar?q=" + query)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like " +
                                "Gecko)" +
                                " Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")
                        .get();

                String title = doc.title();
                System.out.println("title : " + title);


                Elements links = doc.select("div.gs_ggsd").select("a[href]");
                //Element  = doc.select("div.gs_ggs gs_fl").first();

                for (Element link : links) {
                    //System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
                    URL website = new URL(link.attr("href"));
                    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\paper.pdf");
                    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
                }
                // System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's working but the problem is that there are some references tht do have pdf , and some dont.! now the program is running and is still running almost 10 minutes and it is stuck on 2nd reference because there isnt a pdf avaialable for it.! It's in html.!

Comment: continue the loop in the catch block！

Comment: the div i gave the code, where the href of pdf is residing, it is sometimes downloading it and sometimes it is missing a reference in which pdf file is avaialbe. Again what's the issue ??

Comment: Maybe some PDF timeout

Comment: then there must be some check I could use.

Comment: It is not too hard to do this!

Comment: Iam a newbie, Please I cant think of wot to do. ! Please show me.

Comment: @farooqahmed Could you tell me how many total PDF files you want to download ?

Comment: all the avaialble, for example, the research paper i'm currently processing has a total of 10 references, and 5 of them are avaialble in pdf.! the number of references and pdf avaialaibility will vary.

Comment: Just check if the url of pdf is a available with regex.